# Symfony and RDS Replication lag

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, symfony, read-replication

I have a project actually running on Symfony 3.4, and I use AWS RDS Master/Slaves config on a MySQL database.

Sometimes during the day, I have the replication lag increasing for short period. I would like to know if there was a smart way to disable reads from a replica who have over, let's said 5 minutes, of replication lag.

Let me know if you need more information, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PHP mysqlnd replication and load balancing plugin](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd-ms.php), especially [Example 3 on the "Service level and consistency" section](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.quickstart.qos-consistency.php) (sorry no way to direct link) for how to manage maximum age/slave lag.

Personally, I'd also take a look at the [caching options](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.quickstart.cache.php) it offers as well as as the [connection pooling](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.quickstart.connectionpooling.php).

Based on the info in your question, it's hard to give specific advice, but these should give you a good place to start.